# My backbone js router isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, router

I am just starting to learn backbone js. I am not understanding the router. I have written a simple code. What it should do is to print 'I am working' in the console. But it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('this is working');
    }
});
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': function(){
            var a = new AppView();
        }
    }
});
    var ar = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly have a Backbone version problem. The [1.0.0 Change Log entry](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog) says:

> - The routes in a Router's route map may now be function literals, instead of references to methods, if you like.

And you can even find the trivial [one line change](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/commit/e6e7fe878b4b3383d6af8b9677a6ab8ef3aeb84d) in the revision history that made this new behavior possible.

Older versions of Backbone wanted route method names in `routes` and didn't know what to do with functions. Upgrade to the most recent Backbone (and Underscore and jQuery) and your code will work.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sfeCr/1/